# Text normalization : Text similarity in Python. How to normalize Text spelling mismatch?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

i have a dataframe with a column A as below :

```
Column A
Carrefour supermarket
Carrefour hypermarket
Carrefour
carrefour
Carrfour downtown
Carrfor market
Lulu
Lulu Hyper
Lulu dxb
lulu airport
k.m trading
KM Trading
KM trade
K.M.  Trading
KM.Trading
```

I wanted to derive at the below "column A" :

```
Column A
Carrefour
Carrefour
Carrefour
Carrefour
Carrefour
Carrefour
Lulu
Lulu
Lulu
Lulu
KM Trading
KM Trading
KM Trading
KM Trading
KM Trading
```

To do this, i code as below :

```
MERCHANT_NAME_DICT = {"lulu": "Lulu", "carrefour": "Carrefour",  "km": "KM Trading"}

def replace_merchant_name(row):
    """Provided a long merchant name replace it with short name."""
    processed_row = re.sub(r'\s+|\.', '', row.lower()).strip()
    for key, value in MERCHANT_NAME_DICT.items():
        if key in processed_row:
            return value

    return row

frame['MERCHANT_NAME'] = frame['MERCHANT_NAME'].astype(str)
frame.MERCHANT_NAME = frame.MERCHANT_NAME.apply(lambda row: replace_merchant_name(row))
```

But i wanted to use NLP Logic and make it a generic function ( Instead of using values for mapping ). Just call the generic function and run it on any similar data column and get the desired results. I am pretty new to NLP Concepts, so looking for some help on it friends.

NOTE : Basically i wanted a generic NLP way coding to find all similar words from a given column ( or in a list ).

Answer (score 14):

If you don't have a golden set of "right" merchant names, this sounds like a clustering problem. It can be solved with a clever distance function (like Jaro-Winkler from the Jindrich's answer) and a simple clustering algorithm (e.g. agglomerative clustering).

After having clustered the texts, you can find the most representative text from each cluster and replace with it the whole cluster.

```
import numpy as np
import re
import textdistance
# we will need scikit-learn>=0.21
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering  

texts = [
  'Carrefour supermarket', 'Carrefour hypermarket', 'Carrefour', 'carrefour', 'Carrfour downtown', 'Carrfor market', 
  'Lulu', 'Lulu Hyper', 'Lulu dxb', 'lulu airport', 
  'k.m trading', 'KM Trading', 'KM trade', 'K.M.  Trading', 'KM.Trading'
]

def normalize(text):
  """ Keep only lower-cased text and numbers"""
  return re.sub('[^a-z0-9]+', ' ', text.lower())

def group_texts(texts, threshold=0.4): 
  """ Replace each text with the representative of its cluster"""
  normalized_texts = np.array([normalize(text) for text in texts])
  distances = 1 - np.array([
      [textdistance.jaro_winkler(one, another) for one in normalized_texts] 
      for another in normalized_texts
  ])
  clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(
    distance_threshold=threshold, # this parameter needs to be tuned carefully
    affinity="precomputed", linkage="complete", n_clusters=None
  ).fit(distances)
  centers = dict()
  for cluster_id in set(clustering.labels_):
    index = clustering.labels_ == cluster_id
    centrality = distances[:, index][index].sum(axis=1)
    centers[cluster_id] = normalized_texts[index][centrality.argmin()]
  return [centers[i] for i in clustering.labels_]

print(group_texts(texts))
```

The code above will print its output as

```
['carrefour', 'carrefour', 'carrefour', 'carrefour', 'carrefour', 'carrefour', 
 'lulu', 'lulu', 'lulu', 'lulu', 
 'km trading', 'km trading', 'km trading', 'km trading', 'km trading']
```

As a baseline, this function will do. You may want to improve it by modifying the distance function so that it would reflect your domain more closely. For example:

- take into account synonyms: supermarket=hypermarket=market
- lemmatize words (so that trading=trade)
- give smaller weight to the non-important words (IDF?)

Unfortunately, most of such adjustments would be domain-specific, so you will have to tune them to your own dataset.

Comment: Appreciate your response @David Dale. But as i mentioned i have a column in Pandas DF and my function should group the values of that column and replace similar words. I will not be able to get this : texts = [
  'Carrefour supermarket', 'Carrefour hypermarket', 'Carrefour', 'carrefour', 'Carrfour downtown', 'Carrfor market', 
  'Lulu', 'Lulu Hyper', 'Lulu dxb', 'lulu airport', 
  'k.m trading', 'KM Trading', 'KM trade', 'K.M.  Trading', 'KM.Trading'
] . So in that place if i give all the values of the column will it work ?

Comment: Column in a Pandas DF is a pandas.Series. And everything that an ordinary Python array can do, Series can do as well - it's an extension of array. So yes, it will work.

Comment: this is useful for me. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do something as: for each word that is not in a spellchecking vocabulary (and thus is likely to be misspelled), have a look in your list of merchant names and have a look if there is a name with a small edit distance. You can also somehow normalize the words for the similarity search, i.e., lowercase everything and remove punctuation.

You can use [`textdistance`](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) package that implements plenty of string distances. I would probably use [Jaro-Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) for this purpose.

```py
import string
import textdistance

MERCHANT_NAMES = [("lulu", "Lulu"), ("carrefour", "Carrefour"),  ("km", "KM")]
DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 0.9

def normalize(orig_name):
    name_sig = orig_name.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()

    best_score = DISTANCE_THRESHOLD
    replacement = name

    for sig, name in MERCHANT_NAMES:
        distance = textdistance.jaro_winkler(name_sig, sig)
        if distance > best_score:
            best_score = distance
            replacement = name
    return replacement
```

You will probably need to tune what is an acceptable threshold for word replacement and do something with multi-word expressions. (E.g., throw away words similar to "supermarket", "hypermarket", etc.)

Comment: Thanks Jindrich, but i am looking for any working code example.

Comment: Appreciate it , but I am looking for a more generic function which does not require any input as "Carrefour ". It should be able to output all similar syntactical words.